how to focus on EditText inside scrollview
I am struggling with this issue for hours right now. so I have an activity with Toolbar and Scrollbar inside its layout. here is the layout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OperationDashboardActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="#00802B"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        app:title="Input Data"
        app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF" />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tanggal pengamatan" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:paddingVertical="5dp"
                        android:text="date input"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Jam pengamatan" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etTime"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:paddingVertical="5dp"
                        android:text="time input"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/containerInputBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

LinearLayout with ID containerInputBox is a container for many viewgroup with EditText inside of it (please find the attached image). the scrollview is scrolling when Soft keyboard is shown, however not all viewgroups are showing, some of them is still overlapped with the keyboard.
here my class/activity
package com.jasatirta2.sisda

import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.app.TimePickerDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.ScrollView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import com.jasatirta2.sisda.helpers.CustomAlertDialog
import com.jasatirta2.sisda.model.DataPeriodic
import com.jasatirta2.sisda.model.InputData
import com.jasatirta2.sisda.model.ShareData
import okhttp3.Call
import okhttp3.Callback
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import java.io.IOException
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Locale

class OperationInputData : AppCompatActivity() {
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    var token: String? = ""
    val dataPeriodicUrl: String = "https://reference.jasatirta2.id/dataperiodic"
    var locationId = 0
    var locationName: String? = ""
    var date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Date())
    var time = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(Date())
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    private var selectedYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    private var selectedMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    private var selectedDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    private var hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    private var minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
    lateinit var periodics: List<DataPeriodic>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_operation_input_data)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.sisda_token_data), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        token = sharedPref.getString("access_token", "")
        locationName = intent.getStringExtra("location_name")
        locationId = intent.getIntExtra("location_id", 0)

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar).apply {
            subtitle = locationName
        }
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar()!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar()!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        val etDate = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.etDate)
        etDate.text = date
        etDate.setOnClickListener {
            val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
                this,
                { _, selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay ->
                    this.selectedYear = selectedYear
                    this.selectedMonth = selectedMonth
                    this.selectedDay = selectedDay

                    date = String.format(
                        Locale.getDefault(),
                        "%04d-%02d-%02d",
                        selectedYear,
                        selectedMonth + 1,
                        selectedDay
                    )

                    etDate.setText(date)
                },
                selectedYear,
                selectedMonth,
                selectedDay
            )
            datePickerDialog.show()
        }

        val etTime = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.etTime)
        etTime.text = time
        etTime.setOnClickListener {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

            val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
                this,
                { _, selectedHour, selectedMinute ->

                    time = String.format(
                        Locale.getDefault(),
                        "%02d:%02d",
                        selectedHour,
                        selectedMinute
                    )

                    etTime.text = time;
                },
                hour,
                minute,
                true
            )
            timePickerDialog.show()
        }

        val scrollView = findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.sv)

        scrollView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val rect = Rect()
            scrollView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
            val screenHeight = scrollView.rootView.height
            val keypadHeight = screenHeight - rect.bottom

            if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                // Keyboard is opened
                scrollView.post {
                    val mainLayout = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.main)
                    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mainLayout.bottom)
                }
            }
        }

        getData()
    }

    fun getData(){
        val url = "$dataPeriodicUrl/$locationId?token=$token"
        Log.d("SISDA_DEBUG", url)
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()

        val loading = LoadingOverlayDialog(this@OperationInputData).show()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    CustomAlertDialog(this@OperationInputData, "Terjadi kesalahan pada server", "Gagal")
                        .show()
                }
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful){
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                        CustomAlertDialog(this@OperationInputData, "Terjadi kesalahan pada server", "Gagal")
                            .show()
                    }
                }else{
                    val responseBody = response.body!!.string()
                    val dataListType = object: TypeToken<List<DataPeriodic>>() {}.type
                    periodics = Gson().fromJson(responseBody, dataListType)

                    val container = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.containerInputBox)

                    for(data in periodics){
                        val view = renderBox(container, data)
                        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                            container.addView(view)
                        }
                    }
                }

                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    loading.hide()
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    // HERE THE CODE TO ADD viewgroup into `containerInputBox`
    fun renderBox(parent: ViewGroup, data: DataPeriodic): View{
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.operation_input_data_box, parent, false)
        // later i will bind the data to the textview/edittext
        return view
    }
}

in my manifest.xml i've already add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" as well as try another values, still not working as expected. so how can I fix this issue?


Bro you don't have any EditText  in your xml. Check once , I think you mistakenly used x TextView instead of EditText. Or you might have forgot to share the code here.
